# Getting an error when using Gorilla Schema

Tags: web-applications, go, gorilla

I'm trying to use Gorilla's Schema decoder to read in all the post values from my form, but it's not working as expected. I get the schema: invalid path "name" error.

My HTML looks something like this

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="name" required>
</form>
```

My logic for processing the registration form in Go looks something this:

```
err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Form could not be parse")
                return
    }

    var regForm model.RegisterForm // Declare the registration form structure

    decoder := schema.NewDecoder() // Creates a schema decoder
    decoderr := decoder.Decode(&regForm, r.PostForm)
    if decoderr != nil {
        log.Println(decoderr)
                return
    }
    // More code goes here
```

My RegisterForm struct looks something like this:

```
type RegisterForm struct {
    Username string            `schema: "name"`
    Errors   map[string]string `schema: "-"`
}
```

I looked at the docs, but I'm not sure how to match the values of the form properly with my struct.

Comment: I think that space in your schema is actually your issue? http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag . Check out [this playground code](http://play.golang.org/p/DIQ2XtC8C4) and add/remove that space

Comment: It appears that when I change the input name field name="Username" it works, but I'm not exactly sure why though.

Comment: That makes sense though, your struct field is named Usename. It is finding it based off of that. Did you try the simple fix of just removing that space? ie `schema: "name"` --> `schema:"name"`